# App Using Pickle On Python Crashing When Running

Tags: python, python-3.x, crash, pickle

I Have Tried To Make A Simple Notepad App (Not Finished So That's Why "y" is incomplete)

```
import pickle
var1 = input("Open Last Note?(y/n)")
if var1 = "y":


if var1 = "n":
    note = input("Note")
    class MyClass()
        def __init__(self, param):
            self.param = param
 
    def save_object(obj):
        try:
            with open("data.pickle", "wb") as f:
                pickle.dump(obj, f, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
        except Exception as ex:
            print("Error during pickling object (Possibly unsupported):", ex)
 
    obj = MyClass(note)
    save_object(obj)
```

Comment: it should be if var1 == 'y':

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: to make code more readable you could put `class` at the top - after `import`s. Adn `functions` put after `classes`. Don't put `classes` and `functions` inside `if/else` - it can't make code faster, but it make code more readable. See more: [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: I don't know what is your problem but code works for me without crashes.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You app crash becourse here an error. Next sample is uncorrect:

```
if True:

if True:
    #comment
```

You must write `pass` if expression of function don't have body

```
if True:
   pass

if True:
   #comment
   pass
```

Also you can use `Ellipsis`:

```
if True:
    ...
#Elepsis
```

There are another errors in youre code:

```
import pickle
var1 = input("Open Last Note?(y/n)")
if var1 == "y": #need double = in compare
    pass

if var1 == "n": #need == in compare
    note = input("Note")
    class MyClass(): #you miss colon
        def __init__(self, param):
            self.param = param
 
    def save_object(obj):
        try:
            with open("data.pickle", "wb") as f:
                pickle.dump(obj, f, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
        except Exception as ex:
            print("Error during pickling object (Possibly unsupported):", ex)
 
    obj = MyClass(note)
    save_object(obj)
```

Comment: this works but when i try to read the pickle file it just ends (I would leave the error log but it didn't leave one)

Comment: becourse ``if var1=='y': pass`` u need add some action into this block, also logic of app is not good: main action is into 'n' block. I recomend next logic: ```if var1=='y': file=open('pickle.db','wb+'); else: file=open('pickle.db','wb'); #now main code```